# How To Switch Between Forms In Same Form In VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to make a UI that has a few forms / panels, each for a different "Tab" in the program.

I am guessing that the way to do this is using panels and code like:

```
Panel1.Visible = False
Panel2.Visible = False
Panel3.Visible = False
Panel4.Visible = True
```

Would I be correct in assuming that this is the best way to go? (I don't want lots of popup forms in the program, looking for the most streamlined way to go).

Also, if this is the correct way to go how would I go about hiding each panel in the IDE so that I can work on each one seperately using the designer view?

Here is the best example application I can think to use: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPK05.png 
Each of the tabs (Proxies, Harvester etc) has an image as the tab (Which I can't find an option to do with TabControl and then displays the container / panel below it

Comment: If you maybe mock up an example in MS Paint, it would really help visualizing what you want to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide TabControl buttons to manage stacked Panel controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798215/hide-tabcontrol-buttons-to-manage-stacked-panel-controls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like an easier solution, you could always use the TabControl. It will take care of the panels for you and is quite simple to use.

Comment: Here is the best example application I can think to use:
http://i.imgur.com/5SKsA.png

Each of the tabs (Proxies, Harvester etc) has an image as the tab (Which I can't find an option to do with TabControl and then displays the container / panel below it.

Comment: I believe this question has already been answered. You can find what you're looking for right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663603/icons-in-tabcontrol-c-how

Comment: I found pretty much what I was looking for in a third party addon: dotnetbar