# How to create a stylish tab contol with items inside it like visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to develop an application. I want to create a stylish tab control and display pictures like Form1.cs looks like in visual studio tab control ,and i want to highlight it a yellow color when it is clicked.

you can understand by seeing this image,

[image]

There would be a great appreciation if someone could help me.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/ThemedBottomTabNET.aspx

Comment: http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/DockingTabWinForms/

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/CustomTabControl.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663603/icons-in-tabcontrol-c-sharp-how

Comment: i want ditto same as it is like VS 2010 has can u please say me how can i do it . I dont want different tab same as VS 2010 has

Comment: VS2010 built on WPF, so you can achive such style by simple styling of the tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need WPF.

AFAIK, [AvalonDock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com) is one good library made for very similar look. You need to check its forum for examples and latest discussions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation)? The IDE Shell of Visual Studio 2010 (from the screenshot) has been written using WPF.