# How to show an ErrorProvider error icon next to a GroupBox header?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, groupbox, errorprovider

I have a form with a `GroupBox` and an `ErrorProvider`. When I try to use the following code:

```
errorProvider1.SetError(groupBox1, "error");
```

The error icon is shown to the right of the group box:

[image: 1]

I would like the icon to be shown next to the header. Something like this (made with Photoshop):

[image: 2]

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SetIconAlignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.seticonalignment?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`SetIconPadding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.seticonpadding?view=netframework-4.7.2) to set the location of the error icon. For example:

```
errorProvider1.SetError(groupBox1, "Error!");
errorProvider1.SetIconAlignment(groupBox1, ErrorIconAlignment.TopLeft);
errorProvider1.SetIconPadding(groupBox1, -24);
```

You need to shift the text a bit to right, by preppending some space, to have more room for the icon.

Comment: I accept this answer because it works, it addresses the text issue, and it is the first posted.

Answer (score 1):

Following should help you.

```
errorProvider1.SetIconAlignment(groupBox1, ErrorIconAlignment.TopLeft);
errorProvider1.SetIconPadding(groupBox1, -5);
errorProvider1.SetError(groupBox1,"error");
```

As explained in your previous question regarding [TabControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54195451/how-to-show-an-errorprovider-error-icon-next-to-a-tabpage-header/54197434#54197434), you would need to provide sufficient space in your GroupBox Text for showing the icon

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I accepted @Reza Aghaei answer because it was the first.